# Adding superscript to Draftail in Wagtail 2.0

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to add superscript to the new editor in Wagtail.

I see the documentation here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html

Where am I supposed to add the example code?
And am I correct in assuming that I will be able to just change the example from `feature_name = 'strikethrough'` and `type_ = 'STRIKETHROUGH'` to `superscript` and it will work?

Once this is registered, do I have to modify each RichTextField that I have to include it in the `features` setting, or is there a way to add this to all RTF in my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have figured out how to do this, hopefully, someone will correct me if there is a better way!

1. Create a file in one of your registered (in `INSTALLED_APPS`) app directories called `wagtail_hooks.py`.
2. Put the following code in the file:

   ```
   import wagtail.admin.rich_text.editors.draftail.features as draftail_features
   from wagtail.admin.rich_text.converters.html_to_contentstate import InlineStyleElementHandler
   from wagtail.core import hooks

   @hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
   def register_strikethrough_feature(features):
       feature_name = 'superscript'
       type_ = 'SUPERSCRIPT'
       tag = 'sup'

       control = {
           'type': type_,
           'label': '^',
           'description': 'Superscript',
       }

       features.register_editor_plugin(
           'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.InlineStyleFeature(control)
       )

       db_conversion = {
           'from_database_format': {tag: InlineStyleElementHandler(type_)},
           'to_database_format': {'style_map': {type_: tag}},
       }

       features.default_features.append(feature_name)
       features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, db_conversion)
   ```
3. The line `features.default_features.append(feature_name)` is what answers the last part of my question - and is missing from the docs (well, it's there, but not in this context). This adds the feature to all RichTextFields without having to add the `features=[]` setting to each existing and/or new RTF.

To modify this to work with another built in Draftail feature, modify the `feature_name`, `type_`, `tag`, `label`, and `description` fields. Draftail supports the following types:

- Block types: H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, Blockquote, Code, UL, OL, P
- Inline styles: Bold, Italic, Underline, Code, Strikethrough, Mark, Keyboard, Superscript, Subscript
- And HR, BR

With `bold`, `italic`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `ul`, `ol`, `hr`, and `br` already being in the Wagtail default set for a RichTextField.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it for in-line code at the recommendation of Draftail's author, so I think you've got it right!

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it! I don't expect this to be any different from one implementation to the next, so it would be great if you (or anyone else running into this) could make a PR so we have this built-in. The only thing that might change is the label/icon, but we'll see.

Comment: @michael-harrison Have you used this method with a Draftail `code-block`, by chance?

Comment: @Franey - I have not, but just had that request come in, so I will be in the next few days!

Comment: @MichaelHarrison I got close but whitespace isn't preserved ([gist](https://gist.github.com/johnfraney/207004a78b4abd5615ba3a0bcb3cda53))

Comment: You might want to rename the function ;-)
See also https://pypi.org/project/wagtail-draftail-plugins/ or respectively https://gitlab.com/thelabnyc/wagtail-draftail-plugins/blob/master/src/wagtail_draftail_plugins/wagtail_hooks.py

Comment: @user42488 - this would have been great if it had been around when I asked this question! It was released within the last few weeks though: https://pypi.org/project/wagtail-draftail-plugins/#history

Comment: Is it possible to add just a symbol rather than a html tag? Like I want to a button that would just add degree symbol

Answer (score 4):

As of Wagtail [v2.5](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/releases/2.5.html), `superscript` is a built-in format, disabled by default. To use it, all that's needed is to enable it. Either per-field, in the model definition:

```py
    # [...]
    body = RichTextField(features=['superscript'])
    # [...]
```

Or for all editors on a site:

```py
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def enable_superscript_feature(features):
    features.default_features.append('superscript')
```

Note that currently, while superscript will work as expected in the editor, it [won’t be possible to copy-paste content with superscript](https://github.com/springload/draftail/issues/200) from third-party sources (Google Docs, Word, web pages) and have the superscript formatting be preserved.