# How to add superscript to Draftail in Wagtail 2.0

Tags: django, wagtail

I have added superscript to the Draftail editor in Wagtail following these instructions [Adding superscript to Draftail in Wagtail 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264519/adding-superscript-to-draftail-in-wagtail-2-0/54543023#54543023)

It works and renders with the "sup" tag on front end, but does not display as superscript on backend. I've tried adding 'style': 'vertical-align: super' in the feature config, but this does not help. Any suggestions?

```
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_superscript_feature(features):
    feature_name = 'superscript'
    type_ = 'SUPERSCRIPT'
    tag = 'sup'

    # Configure how Draftail handles the feature in its toolbar.
    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'label': 'x²',
        'description': 'Superscript',
        'style': 'vertical-align: super',
    }

    # Call register_editor_plugin to register the configuration for Draftail.
    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.InlineStyleFeature(control)
    )

    # Configure the content transform from the DB to the editor and back.
    db_conversion = {
        'from_database_format': {tag: InlineStyleElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {'style_map': {type_: tag}},
    }

    # Call register_converter_rule to register the content transformation conversion.
    features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, db_conversion)
```

I would like for it to display as superscript in the editor as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding superscript to Draftail in Wagtail 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264519/adding-superscript-to-draftail-in-wagtail-2-0)

Comment: this looks fine, except for `'style': 'vertical-align: super',`, which should be an object, as it uses the JS style API, not the HTML style attribute. `SUPERSCRIPT` styles are actually already provided by the editor (https://github.com/springload/draftail/blob/556d1683a0af0486bf02b0dcbc0714ac98733504/lib/api/constants.js#L104-L108), so this should work by just removing this line.

Comment: Thank you very much @ThibaudColas ! That fixed the problem! For some reason leaving the style off did not work.